# Cocos2d With the map not able to handle all UIEvents

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have cocos2d application which contains the mapview in it , i want to handle the touch,zoom,and other ui event but i am no able to do that cause i have to extend the class with the uiviewcontroller which is not possible cause i have already extended with the CCLayer so can i have some source code to do this

Thanking you.

Rohit

Answer (score 0):

the mapview handles all touch events and when the events happens inside the mapview they are not sent to the controller by default.

A work around for that is to use gesture recognizers in your mapview

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer